# How to have pod replica specific property file in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, containers, kubernetes-pod

I am containerizing spring-boot applications on kubernetes and I want to have a different application property file for each replica of POD.
As I want to have different config for different pod replicas.

Any help on above would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

They're not really replicas if you want a unique configuration for each pod. I think you may be looking for a [`StatefulSet`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/). Quoting from the docs:

> Like a Deployment, a StatefulSet manages Pods that are based on an identical container spec. Unlike a Deployment, a StatefulSet maintains a sticky identity for each of their Pods. These pods are created from the same spec, but are not interchangeable: each has a persistent identifier that it maintains across any rescheduling.

For example, given a StatefulSet like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: example
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: example
  serviceName: "example"
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: example
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: docker.io/nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged:mainline
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: http
```

I end up with:

```
$ kubectl get pod
NAME        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
example-0   1/1     Running   0          34s
example-1   1/1     Running   0          31s
example-2   1/1     Running   0          28s
```

In each pod, I can look at the value of `$HOSTNAME` to find my unique name, and I could use that to extract appropriate configuration from a directory path/structured file/etc.

Comment: I am using statefulset and i have 2 replica for this statefulset and i have cache running on both the replica so I want my cache to update on both the replica. That is the reason where i am looking for different config for both the replica.

Comment: And here I've suggested how you can have a different configuration on your replicas.

Comment: I want to pass application.yml file for this replica based on name. For e.g for pod-0 i have to pass abc.yml and for pod-1 i have to pass xyz.yml

Comment: Mount a directory that has `pod-0.yaml` and `pod-1.yaml`, and then in your application use `/path/to/$HOSTNAME.yaml` as your config file.